# Understanding output streams, buffering and flushes

Tags: c++

In order to output, we have to direct the stream into cout object using << operator. << operator in this case is used as output operator, so if we needed bitwise shift-left operator, we’d have to enclose the expression containing it in parentheses.

What we see printed in terminal is rather a peek at what buffer stores. If not explicitly flushed (with endl or flush), we won’t see these contents, for example in a text file. It’s comparable to what we see after editing a MS Word document but not saving the actual changes. Outputting without flushing is like picking multiple boxes with both arms and putting in the target place once. Outputting with flushing is like picking and putting boxes one by one – like how I tell in this real life example, it’ll take more time.

Overall, flushing won’t be very necessary in your terminal-based executables, since as I told in the beginning we get a peek at the buffer and to see what’s going on anyways. Although, if we were to make real-time logs for our program, flushing may be necessary.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Programmer To correct where I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

The terminal doesn't "peek" at the output, it *displays what it is given, when it is given data to display*.

For an unbuffered output stream that basically means real time. For a buffered output stream, like `ofstream` and `operator<<` provides, it means when the buffer is flushed, or the buffer is full and *must* be flushed anyway. This is effectively an automatic flush.

The same behaviour applies to files, there's no difference. When data is flushed, it appears in the file, but not before. You can see this happen real-time with tools like `tail -f`.

Flushing *will* be necessary in your terminal applications. If you're using `std::endl`, then you're already flushing at end of line, so you probably don't notice any issues. If you use `"\n"` you may need to manually flush at regular intervals or you may notice your output stalls until enough has been accumulated to merit an automatic flush.

In a language like C++ there are two types of "write" calls, one that writes to a buffer, and one that writes using an operating system call. Buffers may or may not be implicitly linked to files. Things like [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) are buffers you can write to, but they're not linked to files.

There's also [`write()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_(system_call)) which does not have a buffer, and every bit of data is *immediately* pushed through to the associated receiver, be it a file, a piped process, network socket, or otherwise.

The important thing to learn here is that there are **user-space writes** and **operating-system writes**. The former is just moving data around in your process, it doesn't leave, like in the case of a buffer. The latter involves data being moved from a user process to the kernel, and possibly forwarded on to another process or file.

What this means from a "buffer peeking" perspective is that's actually impossible, *one process cannot view the contents of another* without some kind of exception permissions, like being attached as a debugger. In normal operation this never occurs. All inter-process communication is mediated by the kernel.

Comment: Now may I ask, why when outputting into terminal with cout, all contents get displayed at once without flushing? When outputting to a text file with ostream or piping the cout output to a text file, nothing will be displayed unless it's flushed.

Comment: Do you use [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)? It "inserts a newline character into the output sequence `os` and flushes it..."

Comment: For example here: `int num;

ofstream fd("stream.txt");
fd << "Hello";
cin >> num;
fd << " world";`, "Hello" and after cin input, " world" would appear in terminal (if I used cout instead of fd), but in text file it'd not. I'm confused why and when I said that it's a peek to buffer, it seemed the most logical to me.

Comment: If the process exits, the output is automatically flushed. What if you put in `sleep(5)` before terminating? With a [test program](http://cpp.sh/55cpb) I get no output until it completes both in that online tester and locally on my (macOS) terminal.

Comment: The only way for the terminal to get output from your process is *if* the buffer is flushed. There is no other mechanism. So either the buffer is being flushed, or you're not creating the conditions where detecting an unflushed buffer is possible.

Comment: I see, so in theory when outputting to terminal, buffer contents are _forced_ to flush? Also why exactly sleep(5) postpones flushing?

Comment: Sleep just stalls the process. As far as your process is concerned there's really no difference between writing to a file or writing to a terminal, they're both just streams. The operating system will forward data if/when it is received, which requires either a buffer flush or a direct write. Nothing is forced. Doing `std::cout << "X"` doesn't actually flush anything. `std::cout << "X" << std::endl` does, as does ending the process.

Comment: What I'm trying to say here is that a lot of the C++ stuff is built up on top of the really low-level `read()` and `write()` system calls. Everything else is just decoration and convenience. Unless a `write()` call is made, no data is sent to that stream. Unless a `read()` call is made on the receiving end, terminal or otherwise, nothing is received.

Comment: Note that both functions take a generic file descriptor which is the POSIX way of saying "file, terminal, network connection, or device" as a lot of things appear to be "files" to POSIX.